# spring xml override utils:list same id

Tags: java, xml, spring

I'm trying to set up a local overrides file for some of my bean definitions. Yes, it's a fragile system, but it's just for testing. Basically, I've got one XML file which looks more or less like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-3.2.xsd">
      <!-- so many beaaaannzzz -->
      <utils:list id="partnerList" value-type="my.partner.Class">
          <ref bean="previouslyDefinedBean"/>
      </utils:list>
      <!-- include local bean definition overrides -->
      <import resource="file://${user.home}/somedirectory/prefix-*.xml"/>
</beans>
```

This works in general, but it has an unexpected and undesirable result with the `utils:list` element.

My `somedirectory/prefix-*.xml` override file defines another list:

```
 <utils:list id="partnerList" value-type="my.partner.class">
     <ref bean="otherBean"/>
 </utils:list>
```

When it is picked up however, I get an undesired result: `partnerList` has two beans in it, `previouslyDefinedBean` and `otherBean`, while I want it to only have the latter.

Now, I'm aware Spring offers some weird weird collection merging, so I tried setting `<utils:list merge="false"...` but that blew up as an unsupported attribute. Is there something I can do to continue using this override system for the `util:list`, or have I got to take another tack entirely?

Comment: `util:list` has never supported the `merge` attribute - that was a documentation error in earlier versions.